# What is the difference between multicollinearity and correlation?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

I have a set of data and I wish to construct a multivariate regression model for predicting. I saw that if the variables are multi-colinear the multivariate regression model will be bad. I don't know how the multi-colinearity conducts to the bad model. And finally I don't what's the difference between correlation and multi-colinearity between variables. How these two concepts impact the model?

Comment: This question has already been answered on the site. Please refer:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/432543/79100